# Creating element using jQuery and adding style attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the following script.  I haven't shown it, but I later further manipulate the DOM.  I get identical results on test 1 and test 2, but get different results using test 3.  What is different with test 3?  Please confirm that the impact of test 1 and test 2 is identical.  If you feel test 3 must provide identical results, I will post my complete code to a fiddle to prove that it isn't.

```
var thead_cells=$('#myTable').children( 'thead' ).find('tr').eq(0).find('th'),

var shimRow=$('<tr />',{height:0,padding:0,margin:0});

for (var i = 0; i < thead_cells.length; i++) {

    //test 1
    shimRow
    .append($('<td />',{height:0,outerWidth:thead_cells.eq(i).outerWidth(true)})
        .css('padding',0)
        .css('margin',0)
        .html(''));

    //test 2
    shimRow
    .append($('<td />',{height:0,outerWidth:thead_cells.eq(i).outerWidth(true), css:{padding:0, margin:0}})
        .html(''));

    //test 3
    shimRow
    .append($('<td />',{height:0,outerWidth:thead_cells.eq(i).outerWidth(true), padding:0, margin:0})
        .html(''));

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether test 1 and test 2 are identical will depend entirely on the styling you have assigned to the `td` element by stylesheets. In test 2, you're overriding any stylesheet-assigned padding and margin; in test 1, you're not.

Test 3 doesn't work because `padding` and `margin` are not properties you can directly assign to `td` elements; that's why there's the `css` part of the previous two, which calls jQuery's `css` function (in jQuery 1.8 and above).

It's worth having a really good read through [the `jQuery(html, attributes)` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes) to understand how test 2 works.

Comment: Thanks TJ.  I spent way to much time on this!  I will read your recommended document in detail!!!